# Osmdroid blank map on some devices

Tags: android, osmdroid

Before marking as a duplicate, please read the question.
I am using osmbonuspack for displaying maps in my app and keep getting blank map on some devices. 
Need help in solving.

1. Yes, I've read all similar questions and tried offered solutions.
2. Yes, I've added write external storage permission to the manifest (and requesting permissions runtime since Marshmallow).
3. Yes, I've tried to use `TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM`,
   but it's not available anymore since July 2016.

Here is the initialisation:

```
    mMapView = (MapView) aq.id(R.id.mapview).getView();
    mMapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);

    mMapController = (MapController) mMapView.getController();
    mMapController.setZoom(14);
    mMyLocationMarker = new MyLocationNewOverlay(getActivity(), mMapView);
    mMyLocationMarker.enableFollowLocation();
    mMapView.getOverlays().add(mMyLocationMarker);
```

Here are manifest permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Open Street Map has changed in the last couple of days. I had the same problem here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921072/osmdroid-maptiledownloader-now-showing-403-forbidden-as-http-response That answer was correct for me.

Comment: Cool, thanks, will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the user agent to your application id. See
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/366

`OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.setUserAgentValue(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);`